# Is there any way to shut down a Hazelcast instance in a JVM?

Tags: java, datagrid, hazelcast

My Java code started numbers of Hazelcast instances in the same JVM (but they are in the same group).

Now I want to shut down some of instances, but not all of them.

I know the method `Hazelcast.shutdownAll()` - this method closes all of the instances. Is there a method that allows to close a specific instance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's very easy - here is the code:

```
HazelcastInstance instance =  Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

instance.getLifecycleService().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 8):

That is correct.

Depending on the Hazelcast version, you can also call `hazelcastInstance.shutdown()`.

Comment: The method isn't deprecated. Please check the documentation.

Comment: You're right. Funnily enough, it was deprecated for some time. The v2.4 documentation shows it as deprecated since v1.9 (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#shutdown()), while the latest documentation no longer shows it as deprecated (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#shutdown()). I stand corrected...

Comment: The plot thickens... The `shutdown` method was in fact gone from the v3.0 release (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html), but it looks like it was brought back in v3.1: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#shutdown() - too funny!

Comment: I put it back because the lifecycle approach caused more complexity for standard cases. But the hzinstance.shutdown just forwards to the lifecycle.shutdown.